# Writing a generic mean function in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a generic mean function that operates on an Iterable that contains numeric types.  It would operate, say, on arrays, as so:

```
val rand = new scala.util.Random()
val a = Array.fill(1000) { rand.nextInt(101) }
val b = Array.fill(1000) { rand.nextDouble }

println(mean(a))
println(mean(b))
```

etc., hopefully being able to work on other iterables, such as lists.

I have tried various incantations for the mean method, to no avail:

```
def mean[T <% Numeric[T]](xs: Iterable[T]) = xs.sum.toDouble / xs.size
def mean[A](xs: Iterable[Numeric[A]]):Double = xs.sum.toDouble / xs.size
def mean[T](xs: Iterable[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]):Double = xs.sum / xs.size
def mean(xs: Iterable[Double]) = xs.sum / xs.size
```

What is the proper way to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 18):

This works:

```
def mean[T : Numeric](xs: Iterable[T]): T = implicitly[Numeric[T]] match {
    case num: Fractional[_] => import num._; xs.sum / fromInt(xs.size)
    case num: Integral[_] => import num._; xs.sum / fromInt(xs.size)
    case _ => sys.error("Undivisable numeric!")
}
```

So, let's make some explanations. First, `Numeric` must be used in type class pattern. That is, you don't say a type `T` is, or can be converted into, `Numeric`. Instead, `Numeric` provides methods over a type `T`. One such example is `num.fromInt`.

Next, `Numeric` does not provide a common division operator. Instead, one must choose between `Fractional` and `Integral`. Here, I'm matching on `Numeric[T]` to distinguish between both.

Note that I don't use `T` on the match, because Scala cannot check for type parameters on matches, as they are erased. Instead, I use `_`, and Scala infers the correct type if possible (as it is here).

After that, I'm importing `num._`, where `num` is either `Fractional` or `Integral`. This brings some implicit conversions into context that let me do stuff like calling the method `/` directly. If I did not do that import, I'd be forced to write this:

```
num.div(xs.sum, num.fromInt(xs.size))
```

Note that I do not have to pass the implicit parameter to `xs.sum`, since it is already implicitly available in the scope.

I guess that's it. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 8):

One of your version is pretty close:

```
def mean[T](xs: Iterable[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]):Double = 
  num.toDouble(xs.sum) / xs.size
```

Here is the other syntax:

```
def mean[T: Numeric](xs: Iterable[T]):Double =
  implicitly[Numeric[T]].toDouble(xs.sum) / xs.size
```

Comment: In Scala 2.9, if you do `import Numeric.Implicits._`, then you can just write `xs.sum.toDouble / xs.size`. I've edited the answer to say so.

Answer (score 4):

```
def mean[A](it:Iterable[A])(implicit n:Numeric[A]) = {
  it.map(n.toDouble).sum / it.size
}
```

Comment: I think SO has some latency/consistency delay recently. It seems some questions have only one or no answers for a while and then suddenly a bunch show up.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question, but I am basically doing this

```
def average[A](list: List[Any])(implicit numerics: Numeric[A]): Double = {
  list.map(Option(_)).filter(_.isDefined).flatten match {
    case Nil => 0.0
    case definedElements => numerics.toDouble(list.map(_.asInstanceOf[A]).sum) / definedElements.length.toDouble
  }
}
```

for a list which might contain `null` values (I have to keep interoperability with Java). The `null` elements are not counted towards the average.