# Too many implicits!

Tags: scala, vector, tuples, implicit

I'm writing a 2D Vector class whose declaration looks like:

```
case class Vec2(x:Float, y:Float) extends (Float, Float)(x, y) {

    def +(v:Vec2) = Vec2(v.x+x, v.y+y)
    //Subtract, dot product, projection, etc.
    ...
    ...
}
```

I'd like to be able to write things like `Vec2(3, 7) + (2, 9)` so I write

```
scala> implicit def ii2v2(i:(Int, Int)) = Vec2(i._1, i._2)
ii2v2: (i: (Int, Int))org.zhang.lib.misc.Vec2

scala> Vec2(2, 6) + (3, 1)
res25: org.zhang.lib.misc.Vec2 = (5.0,7.0)
```

Great. But the implicit won't work if I try `Vec2(3, 7) + (2.6f, 9.3f)`, since `(Float, Float)` doesn't match `(Int, Int)`. The only solution I've come up with is to write FOUR implicits, for `(Int,Int), (Int, Float), (Float, Int), and (Float, Float)`.

The problem gets ridiculous when you try to account for doubles, or when you write a Vec3 class. Is there a way around this? I could just Vec2-ify everything but part of me just really wants to add an (Int, Int) to a Vec2 :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this:

```
implicit def ii2v2[T: Numeric, U: Numeric](i:(T, U)) = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  Vec2(i._1.toFloat, i._2.toFloat)
}
```

This uses context bounds to tell the compiler to look for a Numeric[T] in scope which exist for the numeric types. The import `Numeric.Implicits._` which is available since 2.9, allows to write `toFloat`.

On 2.8 you can write:

```
implicit def ii2v2[T, U](i:(T, U))(implicit num1: Numeric[T], num2: Numeric[U]) = {
  Vec2(num1.toFloat(i._1), num2.toFloat(i._2))
}
```

See this other question which is similar: [Writing a generic mean function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188990/writing-a-generic-mean-function-in-scala)

Comment: Cool stuff! I'll have to look more into Numeric. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna check out [Numeric](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/Numeric.scala.html). Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252915/scala-how-to-define-generic-function-parameters).