# python numpy std vs scala breeze stddev

Tags: python, scala, scala-breeze

I'm currently working on migrating some python code to scala. I'm using breeze lib as a substitution for numpy.

Everything looks fine, but I faced different behaviour in output of standard deviation implementations:

Python:

```
series = np.array([1,4,5])
np.mean(series) // 3.3333333333333335
np.std(series) // 1.699673171197595
```

Scala:

```
val vector = breeze.linalg.Vector[Double](Array(1.0, 4.0, 5.0))
val mean = breeze.stats.mean(vector) // 3.3333333333333335
val std = breeze.stats.stddev(vector) // 2.081665999466133
```

I know how to reproduce python's behaviour in plain scala. Sample code is presented here: [Scala: What is the generic way to calculate standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617213/scala-what-is-the-generic-way-to-calculate-standard-deviation)

But I'm looking for a way to get it with breeze. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the number of [degrees of freedom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58230/degrees-of-freedom-for-standard-deviation-of-sample). Indeed,

```
>>> np.std(series, ddof=1)
2.081665999466133
```

Which is the sample std. With breeze, something you can do to get the population std is

```
var n   = 3
val std = breeze.stats.stddev(vector)*Math.pow((n-1)/n, .5)
# 1.6996731711975948
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I've found related issue in breeze GitHub page:
https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues/507

Comment: @Normal This may be something you know but see my update regarding how to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If keepAlive's solution don't work, you should change "n" to Double

```
var n : Double  = 3
val std = breeze.stats.stddev(vector)*Math.pow((n-1)/n, .5)
# 1.6996731711975948
```